# Implement `Eq`/`Ord` for infinitely recursive data type

Tags: haskell, recursive-datastructures

I want to build NFAs that match strings. I have:

```hs
data State = State Char State | Split State State | Final
```

Note that `State` can be infinitely recursive on purpose, because I want to be build NFAs like the one below:

```hs
-- NFA for regex `1*`
match1 = State '1' loop; loop = Split match1 Final
```

When executing such an NFA against a string I have to keep track of already visited states in order to break cycles. I do this with a `Set` which in turn requires `State` to implement `Ord`. However the derived `Ord` instance's `compare` of course has the same problem that it keeps recursing.

How would I go about solving this? I've looked at [`StableName`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/System-Mem-StableName.html), but `makeStableName` uses the `IO` monad and thus cannot be used when implementing `compare` (AFAIK).

The only thing I can think of right now is to add some kind of id to a `State` for tracking:

```hs
data State = State Int Char State | Split Int State State | Final
```

But that feels rather unelegant especially considering that client code would have to ensure its uniqueness.

Comment: You can't do this with this data structure.  There is no way to tell if you've already visited a state.  You will e.g. need to number your states.

Comment: [possibly relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28243314)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR: don't add `State`s to a `Set`, but implement `instance Hashable State` using `StableName State` and add to a `HashSet` instead.**

As pointed out in the comments this problem is not easily solved without tagging each state with some kind of unique id.

My first attempt was to just add an `Int` to the `State` and `Split` ctor, but this didn't go well with the way the NFA is build. Since this is not done by client code directly, but by a builder (which in turn is used by a parser) which then would have to auto-generate unique ids.

It seemed possible with a state monad, but the problem was that the implemention would keep generating new unique ids for states that have already been "id'ed" due to cycles in the NFA.

What ultimately pushed me in the right direction was the mentioning of [Data.Reify](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-reify-0.6.3/docs/Data-Reify.html) in a (now deleted) comment.

Data.Reify relies on [`StableName`s](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/System-Mem-StableName.html) and a `HashMap` to detect cycles so I figured I could do the same by implementing `Hashable` for `State` with the help of `StableName`.

The following is what I ended up with.

Preamble:

```hs
import qualified Control.Monad.State.Lazy as M
import Data.Hashable
import qualified Data.HashMap.Lazy as Map (empty, insert, lookup)
import Data.HashMap.Lazy (HashMap)
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import System.Mem.StableName (eqStableName, makeStableName)
```

The relevant types again (because I changed them by now):

```hs
data State = State {accepts :: Match, next :: State}
           | Split {left :: State, right :: State}
           | Final

data Match = AnyChar
           | LiteralChar Char
           | CharRange (Char, Char)
           deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Implementation of `Hashable` (requires `Eq`);

```hs
instance Eq State where
  x == y = unsafePerformIO $
    M.liftM2 eqStableName (makeStableName x) (makeStableName y)

instance Hashable State where
  hashWithSalt salt state = unsafePerformIO $
    hashWithSalt salt <$> makeStableName state
```

I see three possbile issues with this implemention:

1. The same `State` may have a different `StableName` after evaluation. This is  known `StableName` behavior and non-issue during NFA execution, because in the worst case a `Split` will be followed twice when figuring out the next possible states reachable without consuming input.
2. By the same token `(==)` might return `False` for the same `State`. I have no clue of the implications as of yet ‍♂️
3. I have no clue how safe `unsafePerformIO` is in this scenario. But I've seen other code doing something very similar and the Data.Reify docs say something vague about that it should be safe.

The implementation of the NFA execution works for now in the presence of loops as does the implementation of `instance Show State`.